# C++/Arduino flash LED different intervals

Tags: c++, arduino

I have the following code on an Arduino where I want to flash a LED with the following rules:

The LED shall flash two times fast and then pause for a longer duration, so that the following rythm is achieved:

ON-ON----ON-ON----ON-ON ...
On should last 125 ms, the short pause should last 75 ms and the long one 500 ms.

Here is what I've done so far:

```
unsigned long flashOn = 125;
unsigned long flashOff = 75; //first pause must be a short one
unsigned long flashCount = 0;
void handleFrontFlash() {
  byte beforeState = digitalRead(LED_Front);
  flashOff = (flashCount % 2 > 0) ? 75 : 500;
  digitalWrite(LED_Front, (millis() % (flashOn + flashOff)) < flashOn);
  byte afterState = digitalRead(LED_Front);
  if(beforeState == LOW and afterState == HIGH)
    flashCount++;
}
```

My idea was to count the times the LED is switched to on and use a modulo to determine, if the cycle is completed. However, the double-flash is only achieved every 8th flash of the LED, the rest of the time the LED flashes once.
Can someone help me here?

Comment: You should learn basic debugging techniques. Such as writing log messages that dump the values of all variables. Or, how to write unit tests. Here, for example, the unit test would invoke this function, repeatedly, and observe the results. Acquiring basic debugging skills will have far more benefit, in terms of learning how to debug one's own code, and gaining debugging experience; after which it will no longer be necessary to seek help on stackoverflow.com every time your program doesn't work. You will be able to figure it out yourself. Don't you think that doing this makes far more sense?

Comment: Debugging and Arduino should not be used in one sentence, same for unit tests

Comment: Of course it should be. There's nothing here that prevents a thorough unit test from being written. C++ has many powerful tools for that. Like macros and preprocessing. It shouldn't be very difficult to sprinkle a bunch of macros here that compile down to the same exact code, by default, but with appropriate `#define`s will compile down to something that drive a debugging class that represents simulated debugging hardware, and records the operations on it (led on/off, delay, etc...)

Comment: Debugging on an arduino is a difficult process, as in many small embedded systems because of the limited program and memory space as well as the "operating system" that comes along with the arduino environment. If one is not extremely knowledgeable and careful the simple act of writing a log message can substantially change how the total software on the board runs. One technique that works is to develop small algorithm pieces on a PC with a good debugging environment, then copy them into the arduino environment.

Comment: As for the OP problem. I would approach this by using a state machine. Use an interval that is a common divisor of the LED state periods, say 25. Use enough states to accommodate the full sequence. So states 0..4 the LED will be on, 5..7 off and so on. Each time through the loop you advance the state by 1 or loop back to zero and set the LED to the appropriate value. Once it is working you can simplify the state space, if you want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an example of what you want, i have used simple functions to easy understant the program, i am using LED_BUILTIN wich is the led 13 of arduino uno or mega

```
unsigned long currentMillis;
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
unsigned long interval;
int Compteur = 1;
int ledState = HIGH;
int state = 0;

void setup(){
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH); // i begin with HIGH during 125ms
  interval = 125;
  previousMillis = 0;
}

// Main loop
void loop() {
  currentMillis = millis(); 
  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {

    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    switch (state) {
      case 0:
        ledState = LOW;
        interval = 75;
        state = 1;
        break;
      case 1:
        ledState = HIGH;
        interval = 125;
        state = 2; 
        break;
      case 2:
        ledState = LOW;
        interval = 500;
        state = 3; 
        break;
      case 3:
        ledState = HIGH;
        interval = 125;
        state = 0;
        Compteur++; // count the number of beginning new sequence         
        break;            
      default:
      // statements
      break;
    }
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, ledState);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not think about using switch-case here :)

Answer (score 1):

If all you need to do is repeat that same pattern you might be able to do it a bit more simply...

```
unsigned long on = 125;
unsigned long shortOff = 75;
unsigned long longOff = 500;

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  delay(on);   
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
  delay(shortOff);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  delay(on);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
  delay(longOff);
}
```

If you need to do something else 'concurrently' then  [the answer by Frenchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53978811/c-arduino-flash-led-different-intervals/53979983#53979983)  would be better.

Comment: that was my first solution, but I have an IR receiver and some other flashlights running so i cannot use loops or delays. But since this answer will produce the desired outcome, I'll give it an upvote:)